# Bitbucket api returns 400 for commit pull requests

Tags: bitbucket-api

I'm trying to get the list of pull requests for a given git commit in Bitbucket.  I can successfully curl both the commit, and the list of pull requests:

```
curl -u $USER:$APP_TOKEN https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/meekrosoft/demo_bitbucket_pipe/commit/d7f5d5b11b268a70684f8683b411caed57da9d34/
curl -u $USER:$APP_TOKEN https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/meekrosoft/demo_bitbucket_pipe/pullrequests
```

However when I try to get the [pull requests for a commit](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bcommit%7D/pullrequests) that has an associated pull request I get a 400 error:

```
curl -u $USER:$APP_TOKEN https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/meekrosoft-ztl/test_pipe/commit/d7f5d5b11b268a70684f8683b411caed57da9d34/pullrequests 
{"error": "Invalid or unknown installation"}%
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be some kind of new feature that you can only select once you view a pull in the user interface

[image]

Comment: Had a similar issue. Although I was visualising the PR and extracted the commit from there, only after going to the commit and click on the button (on the right panel) to jump to the pull requests, it unblocked the API

Answer (score 2):

Per the Bitbucket docs: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bcommit%7D/pullrequests

> Pull Request Commit Links app must be installed first before using
> this API; installation automatically occurs when ‘Go to pull request’
> is clicked from the web interface for a commit’s details.

I tried to do it in Chrome but it didn't work (console said something about CSP). I was able to do it in Safari and get this endpoint to work. You'll have to do this once per workspace.